# Creating a string counter - segmentation faults occuring and I'm unsure why

Tags: c, counter

my code is meant to create a counter in the order "a", "b" ... "z", "aa" .. "az", "aaa" ... "aaz" etc.

```
void incrementCounter(char *counter) {
  int length = strlen(counter);
  if (counter[length-1] == 'z') {
    counter = realloc(counter, sizeof(char) * (length+2));
    counter[length] = 'a';
    counter[length+1] = '\0';
  } else {
    counter[length-1]++;
  }
}
```

However I segmentation fault on line 7 after calling incrementCounter("a");

Any help on how to fix this or how to write a better counter, it just needs to be strings and be different from every previous element?

Comment: "a" is a string constant. You shouldn't modify it.

Comment: Use a debugger to find which line that segfaults and check if counter is NULL after realloc

Comment: am I not passing the pointer to it? so shouldn't I be able to change the value at a specific index in the char *counter

Comment: It failed on line 7 (counter[length-1]++), it doesn't even get to the realloc line - checked with gdb

Comment: @dilan_s yes, you are passing a pointer to "a" which is a string literal and which cannot be modified.

Comment: I look forward to the year 4545 when C finally fixes this.

Comment: Off-topic: silly counter format. Why is `az` incremented to `aaa` rather than `ba`? Your counter will be growing linear rather than logarithmic.

Comment: @underscore_d It will not happen before people stop using IRC :D

Comment: Also, since you realloc your counter, you'll want to pass it in as `**counter`  (so you can directly modify your callers *counter to point to the newly allocated memory) or return counter rather than void (like realloc does).

Comment: @dilan_s, Re "*am I not passing the pointer to it?*, Yes, but you dereference that pointer. `char c = 'a'; char *p = &c; p[0] = 'b';` boils down to `char c = 'a'; c = 'b';`  What memory do you think your changing if not the memory in which the two-char string is stored?

Comment: @gmatht Nitpick: Officially, It is called *string literal*, not *string constant*.

Comment: @underscore_d [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385970/creating-a-string-counter-segmentation-faults-occuring-and-im-unsure-why#comment110335682_62385970) - To what are you referring to? To be able to modify a string literal?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, i.e. the fact that they're not formally `const`, so users think they can modify them because the compiler lets them, but then they get UB and wonder why.

Comment: @underscore_d some compilers offer `-Wwrite-strings`, which fixes it if you also treat warnings as errors

Comment: @underscore_d Ah, yes, that's really annoying. Standard should fix this as soon as possible. - BTW I thought first you want to be able to modify string literals. :-)

Comment: This is not C++, this is C!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The memory created by string literals such as `"a"` should not be modified.

This is bad:

```
incrementCounter("a");
```

The following allocates some memory you can modify, and this memory is initialized as you would expect:

```
char counter[] = "a";
incrementCounter(count);
```

However, that won't work either because `incrementCounter` tries to reallocate the pointer. You need a pointer created with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` to do that.

You can use any of the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *s = malloc(2);
s[0] = 'a';
s[1] = 0;

incrementCounter(s);
```

or

```
#include <string.h>

char *s = malloc(2);
strcpy(s, "a");

incrementCounter(s);
```

or

```
#include <string.h>

char *s = strdup("s");
incrementCounter(s);
```

Comment: Your understanding of a *string constant* is quite interesting, tough. From where you got this? I can't find it in the standard.

Comment: @RobertS supports Monica Cellio, I don't know what the standard calls the memory allocated by `"a"`. Like I said, if there was a better expression for it, I was open to using it. But it's all moot now :)

Answer (score 1):

A quoted string "a" is a string literal. Modifying it is undefined behaviour, and you shouldn't `realloc` it.

You can convert "a" into a string you can modify by using malloc and strcpy. For example:

```
a = malloc(2);
if (a) {
    strcpy(a, "a");
    incrementCounter(a);
}
```

See e.g. https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/CharacterStrings.html#:~:text=A%20String%20Literal%2C%20also%20known,terminted%20by%20a%20null%20byte.

Comment: It's called string literal, not string constant.

Comment: @klutt It's a string constant in C.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No it's not. It's UB to modify it though, but the type is `char[]` and not `const char[]`

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, And the spec calls them string literals. See [page 70](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (which is on page 88 of the PDF)

Comment: That said, "string literal" refers to the code itself.  A literal is a piece of code. It's not clear whether gmatht is talking about the code or the value in memory when they say "string literal"

Comment: @klutt My mistake - int/char/bool literals are called "constants" in C (they're literals in C++). I didn't realise string literals were named differently. How confusing.

Comment: BTW regardless of type "constant" _is_ a proper description of their semantics.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well, yes or no depending on what you mean. If it truly were a constant, one would expect the compiler to issue an error or at least a warning.

Comment: @klutt You'd want it to, but, as we know, that is not the case for these, and I don't think that makes it non-constant :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings string literals are not `const`, and it is undefined to modify. Some systems allow modifying them. (compilers may put their own definition for things that are undefined by the standard)

Comment: @M.M Thank you I'm obviously aware of that? I said _constant_, not `const`.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think calling them "constants" would just lead to more confusion, since you'd expect a constant to be const. I understand what you mean, but tbh, I think the only solution is to teach people the whole picture in this case. Any simplification would just lead to confusion. Teach people what UB is and teach them that it's UB to modify them. That's correct and enough.

Comment: @klutt I wholly agree that actually calling them "string constants" is not as good as calling them "string literals". I'm glad to discover that C indeed does that. And, for the record, I never suggested not teaching any of that ;)